# How to create a double spend to prioritize a new transaction over a previous unconfirmed transaction?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, doublespend, bitcore

I'd like to generate a double spend transaction and increase the gas fees over the previous, unconfirmed transaction that has been stuck for a week. I know there's other answers regarding double spend but I'm looking for more of a technical answer specific to my thought process and sample code.

I understand the general premise is to recreate the originating transaction in its entirety. I've started by utilizing `bitcore-lib` to perform a `getRawTransaction` of my currently stuck transaction. From here, I'm iterating over the `vin` and performing a `getRawTransaction` of the vin's `txid` to retrieve the parent. I'm then parsing the parent, iterating over each `vout` and looking for `vout.n` to match the previous `vin.vout`. Once I find a match, I'm generating a `utxo` which effectively looks like this:

```
const utxo = {
    address: output.scriptPubKey.addresses[0],
    txId: vin.txid,
    outputIndex: vin.vout,
    script: output.scriptPubKey,
    satoshis: output.value
};
```

I then use these utxos to generate and sign the transaction as follows (sorry for lack of full class, but the actual process of signing transactions is fully functional):

```
const transaction = new Bitcore.Transaction();

transaction.fee(this.fee());
transaction.from(utxos);
targets.forEach((target) => {
    transaction.to(target.address, this.amountToSatoshis(target.amount));
});
transaction.change(address);
transaction.sign(this.privateKey(privateKey));
```

**So my questions are...**

1. Is my thought process correct in how I could go about regenerating the original transaction for submission by `bitcore`?
2. Is there an easier way to regenerate the transaction and increase the fees than how I'm trying to do it?
3. When attempting to replicate/duplicate the previous utxos, would I want to also provide the `sequence` number in the utxo?
4. Will this even work or will I even be able to submit this transaction to my same core node?
5. If it won't work, would it work if I ran `-zapwallettxes` on the core node first?

Comment: You are probably better off just doing a Child Pays For Parent transaction, assuming there was a change output and/or you are the recipient.

Comment: In this scenario, I am the sender wishing to increase the gas fees of my sent transaction @m1xolyd1an. It's currently being sent to an exchange address I don't control.